# Forgot Password with REST API Connector: How to send email as input claim?

Tags: rest, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am trying to send a user's email and password to a REST API as a part of the Forgot Password custom policy user journey. This serves a business need for us, as we are doing a staggered release of the B2C Client and need to temporarily keep our IDP's in sync.

I have got this sample custom policy to work except for the email address. password is sending properly.

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/store-three-letters-of-the-password

Here is the technical profile I wrote:

```
 <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-SyncPassword">
         <DisplayName>Update Password</DisplayName>
         <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
         <Metadata>
             <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://ourapi/api/v1/Identity/UpdatePW</Item>
             <Item Key="AuthenticationType">ApiKeyHeader</Item>
             <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
                   <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">false</Item>
         </Metadata>
         <CryptographicKeys>
             <Key Id="SPECIAL-KEY-HEADER" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_RestApiKey"/>
         </CryptographicKeys>
         <InputClaims>
             <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true" /> <!-- DOESN'T WORK -->
             <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName"/> <!-- WORKS -->
             <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" PartnerClaimType="password"/> <!-- WORKS -->
         </InputClaims>
     <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
 </TechnicalProfile>
```

This is included as a Validation Technical Profile in

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId">
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="Get-requiresMigration-status-password-reset" ContinueOnError="false" />
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-FlipMigratedFlag" ContinueOnError="false">
    <Preconditions>
      <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
        <Value>requiresMigration</Value>
        <Value>False</Value>
        <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
      </Precondition>
     </Preconditions>
   </ValidationTechnicalProfile>
   <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId"/> <!-- Attempt to get email-->
   <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-SyncPassword"/>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

I understand that in order to access the value as an Input Claim it must be an Output Claim of a previous step (or maybe I don't understand apparently). We have a previous step already "AAD-FlipMigratedFlag" that outputs userPrincipalName although this isn't the value we need. I attempted to get the email by calling "AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" to get email but this did not work as I still only see 'password' on the request body.

Here is the "AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" profile from the starter park:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId">
   <Metadata>
     <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
     <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
   </Metadata>
   <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
   <InputClaims>
     <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
   </InputClaims>
   <OutputClaims>
   <!-- Optional claims -->
     <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
     <!--<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />-->
     <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
     <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
     <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
   </OutputClaims>
   <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

How do I get the user's email address sent to our REST API as a part of this Forgot Password User Journey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId", change:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
```

to:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly. To not interfere with other profiles also using "AAD-UserReaderUsingObjectId" I simply renamed the profile and added it to the Extensions.xml.